# How to get array value within the indexPath into other methods?

Tags: string, uitableview, nsmutablearray, didselectrowatindexpath

In my app i am Passing an array like "idStr = [idArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];" in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath. How to get that value into another method? I want to pass that idStr to my below Method. any Help?

```
-(void)test
{
 NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:GETLIST,UDID,idStr];
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Is GETLIST a format string?  What are you trying to accomplish?  You should clarify your question.

Comment: @Jerry in what ever in the "idStr" i want to pass that string into my -(void)test method